# A confusion about the alias area of bashrc file

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I want write my own alias called `oepnserver`. The functions of the `oepnserver` are:

- show my ip address
- use python module to start a server on current folder.

The detailed code is listed below:

```
alias openserver="ifconfig wlan0 |grep inet\ |awk '{print $2}' && python3 -m http.server 54188"
```

When I type `oepnserver`, my terminal only shows:

```
        inet 172.34.162.200  netmask 255.255.224.0  broadcast 172.34.191.255
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 54188 (http://0.0.0.0:54188/) ...
```

However, my expectation was

```
172.34.162.200
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 54188 (http://0.0.0.0:54188/) ...
```

I also try to use the `ifconfig wlan0 |grep inet\ |awk '{print $2}'` along, and I get the correct output.

Should I use another way to combine these two commands instead of `&&`? Or I just made some typo?

Comment: No, `&&` is correct, assuming you only want python to run if all of the preceding commands succeeded. The ```\``` at the end of ```inet\``` is suspicious and you not surrounding that whole argument with single quotes is wrong. I would have said the more likely issue is that ifconfig is printing to stderr instead of stdout but if the command works from the command line then it can't be that.

Comment: @EdMorton Thank you, I'll try it again based on your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your shown code I am trying to optimize it which could be done by single awk.

```
ifconfig wlan0 | awk '/inet /{print $2}' && your python code
```

Also IMHO you should try to make this as a function rather than alias.

Comment: The conclusion is alias way (even use your answer) cannot suit my needs...,  but your answer also gives me the good advice that let `alias` do what it should instead of taking over the `function` job. I recode `openserver` in `function` way and solve my problem. Thank you.